# Cannot Read The Property Of "Discord.MessageEmbed()"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have like no coding Experiance and was Directed here to ask this question.
So I would Like Some help please ;-; [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW3g3.png)
I have no idea what im doing lol
I just watched 5 videos on how to make a Discord Bot

Comment: Did you install the packages correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your first line into:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

And you have to remove the `Discord` parameter from your execute function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend getting an understanding about Node.JS before developing a Discord BOT. Anyway from the screenshot you have provided you I can see the issue. Looks like you are using a command handler and the first line is incorrect it should be `const discord = require ("discord.js");`.

As you are using a command handler creating a new command is simple, create a new file in the commands folder calling it whatever you want, for example ping.js. Then add the following code.

```js
const discord = require ("discord.js");

exports.run = (client, message, args) =>{
    message.channel.send ('pong!')
}
```

And since you wanted to send an embed this is how you can do it (This will also fix your issue)!

```js
const discord = require ("discord.js");

exports.run = (client, message, args) =>{
    const help = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#002fff')
    .setTitle('List of commands')
    .addField("blah blah", "blah blah")
    message.channel.send({embed: help })
};
```